# Is there a way to make attr_reader create methods with a different name than the instance variable?

Tags: ruby, attributes, conventions, standard-library

In Ruby, is there a way to do something like

```
class Foo
    attr_reader :var_name :reader_name #This won't work, of course
    def initialize
        @var_name = 0
    end
end

# stuff here ....

def my_method
    foo = Foo.new
    assert_equal 0,foo.reader_name
end
```

In other words, is there a standard way to make an accessor method for a variable that uses a different name than the variable. (Besides hand-coding it, of course.)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It's probably bad practice.

Comment: When your internal names are different than the external interface specification.  This came up working on the about_dice_project ruby-koan.  They want to call the list of rolled dice formed most recently `values`.  I want to call it `@lastRolled`.  One refers to the way it is implemented (as an internal variable should) and the other refers to the way the specifier was thinking about it.  In this case it doesn't matter a bit, but I could see it being something I might want to know in the future.

Comment: upvote for well written Q. I don't have to like what your asking ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`alias_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-alias_method):

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :var_name
  alias_method :reader_name, :var_name
  def initialize
    @var_name = 0
  end
end
```

The `var_name` method built by `attr_reader` would still be available though. You could use [`remove_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-remove_method) to get rid of the `var_name` method if you really wanted to (but make sure you get everything in the right order):

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :var_name
  alias_method :reader_name, :var_name
  remove_method :var_name
  def initialize
    @var_name = 0
  end
end
```

If you really wanted to, you could monkey patch an `attr_reader_as` method into Module:

```
class Module
  def attr_reader_as(attr_name, alias_name)
    attr_reader attr_name
    alias_method alias_name, attr_name
    remove_method attr_name
  end
end

class Foo
  attr_reader_as :var_name, :reader_name
  def initialize
    @var_name = 0
  end
end
```

A better `attr_reader_as` would take a hash (e.g. `{ var_name: :reader_name, var_name: :reader_name2}`) but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass any options to attr_reader

Is this a handcoding?

```
class Foo
  def initialize
      @var_name = 0
  end
  def reader_name; @var_name; end
end
```

Comment: +1 for "don't be so lazy and do it yourself". Sorry for wrecking your cool and lucky 8888 reputation.

Comment: Yes, it is a hand-coding.  But your response lets me know that it is likely most ruby programmers would do it that way.  [Laziness is a virtue](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LazinessImpatienceHubris) of course.

Answer (score 3):

First off, my mantra: **A good programmer plays his teammates good. Following conventions is playing others good.**

What you want seems unconventional, and as @edgerunner states, bad practice (read: I would've smacked you). All I'm saying, think twice about this, I don't know your use case, it might prove valid... Anyway, a little fun during easter should be allowed, so I practiced some metaprogramming and played with Mixins.

```
class Foo
  include MyAttrReader
  my_attr_reader :var_name, :reader_name
  def initialize
    @var_name = 0
  end
end
```

pretty clean. The module does the trick (be sure to load this module before the class)

```
module MyAttrReader
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def my_attr_reader(attribute, read_attribute)
      define_method "#{read_attribute}" do
        instance_variable_get "@#{attribute}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Testing in irb

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > load 'my_attr_reader.rb'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > load 'foo.rb'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > f = Foo.new
 => #<Foo:0x00000100979658 @var_name=0> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > f.reader_name
 => 0 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > f.var_name
NoMethodError: undefined method `var_name' for #<Foo:0x00000100979658 @var_name=0>
```

I hope you see how unintuitive this will be for others. You could override the to_s method to show how to access @var_name, but I wouldn't go there... or define the var_name method too (two getter-methods). Stick to conventions. Anyhow, I had great fun, good luck!